# Django Rest Framework Token Auth > Remove user foreign Key from POSTs while keeping it for GETs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling to make this work.
I have the following model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField("date published")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['id', 'text', 'date', 'user', 'room']
```

I've changed the serializer to have the user "expanded" when I retrieve my Message list with a GET request.

So what I hoping to achieve - with my token authentication - is to avoid passing the user in my POST request. As I pass the token for authentication, there should be a way to retrieve the user with it.

Here are my ViewSets:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class MessageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        authentication_classes = []
        room_id = self.request.query_params.get('room_id')
        return Message.objects.filter(room=room_id)
```

My settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not really following what you aim to achieve?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem My GET request is fine as is, but I want to avoid passing the user for a POST request by using the token. I don't know how to change the serializer to do that.

Comment: So you want to use the ologged in user when creating an item?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [**`CurrentUserDefault()`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) as value, this will then use the user from the context:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['id', 'text', 'date', 'user']
```

Comment: Looks perfect but I have this error: 
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: chat_message.user_id`

Comment: @lorenzo: did you customize the `ViewSet` somehow? You need to let Django construct the serializer with the context correcly.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the ViewSets, not sure if they're bad. Thanks!

Comment: @lorenzo: your `ViewSet` doesn't have an `authentication_classes`? Did you set authentication in the `ViewSet`?

Comment: I don't. I have some default settings from the settings.py, is that not enough?